# UI testing - how to check that I am in right controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have button in my controller and after click on button I made request and check the result. If it is error than I show alert else I perform segue to another controller. I would like to have UI tests for this. This is how end of my test methods looks like:

```
func testExample() {
  ...
  elementsQuery.buttons["CreateAccount"].tap()

  XCTAssertEqual(app.navigationBars.element.identifier, "ProgrammeViewController")
}
```

I get break at last line. I think I didn't set it right. But I am not sure how to set it. I have title in that controller but I change it for each language. So I want to use `accessibilityLabel`. I tried:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.accessibilityLabel = "ProgrammeViewController"
self.navigationItem.accessibilityLabel = "ProgrammeViewController"
```

But it didn't help. So what's the right way to do this? And should I set `accessibilityLabel` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? I think if I want to use this for multiple controllers then the `viewWillAppear` would be better right? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

Set `accessibilityIdentifier` instead of `accessibilityLabel`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.accessibilityIdentifier = "ProgrammeViewController"
```

#### Long Answer:

From [UIAccessibilityIdentification protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityIdentification_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)UIAccessibilityIdentification):

> The UIAccessibilityIdentification protocol is used to associate a unique identifier with elements in your user interface. You can use the identifiers you define in UI Automation scripts ...

This document is a bit outdated since it talks about *UI Automation* (Apple's UI Testing framework before Xcode 7). The point is that, for UI Testing, it recommends using the property (`accessibilityIdentifier`) defined in this protocol.

And, from [UIAccessibility protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityLabel) on accessibilityLabel:

> If an accessibility element does not display a descriptive label, set this property to supply a short, localized label that succinctly identifies the element. For example, a “Play music” button might display an icon that shows sighted users what it does. To be accessible, however, the button should have the accessibility label “Play” or “Play music” so that an assistive application can provide this information to users with disabilities.

So `accessibilityLabel` is to help disabled users.

**Discussion:** While you can use both `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityIdentifier` in UITesting code because, after all, UI Testing is like a User going through our application, If the soul purpose is to identify an element, Do not use *label*.

**Always use `accessibilityIdentifier` to *identify* an element**

`accessibilityLabel` is **not** to identify elements. It is to help people with disabilities. Testing that it is set correctly is a valid test. For example, one could write a test for *Stop* icon that checks that `accessibilityLabel` for it is indeed `"Stop"` (or a localized variant) instead of some other string.

Ideally, `accessibilityLabel` ***should change*** depending on user's locale, `"Stop"` should become `"رکیے"` in Urdu. However, `accessibilityIdentifier` should stay the same. The user never sees it. It is there for you, the programmer, to identify elements in UI Testing. `accessibilityIdentifier = "MusicPlayerController"` will stay `"MusicPlayerController"` regardless of the user's locale.

**Where to set `accessibilityIdentifier`**

It does not matter whether you set it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` as long as it is set by the time UI gets displayed. I tend to set these in Storyboard (or .Xib). Not all controls expose this field in Storyboard though e.g. `UITableView`, for these I set it in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an extension to the answer already given. Like @ishaq already said, the storyboard does not provide `Accessibility` attributes for every component. But you can use `User Defined Runtime Attributes` to set `accessibilityIdentifier` easily within storyboards too.

[image]